# $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with two global minima and no other stationary points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let us take $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ prove that there exists an $f$ in this space such that:

1. $f$ has only two global minima
2. $f$ has no maximum

This is easy to prove, but the following it's pretty hard.

Prove that there exists an $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that:

1. $f$ has only two global minima
2. $f$ has no other stationary point

Now I tried to prove this with the topological theorem that (said as informally as I can) says that the level curves of $f$ changes when there is a stationary point. Starting from this theorem I want to show that there exists a function that puts the stationary point that we expect to be between the two global minimun at $\infty$ meant as the $\infty$ point of the Alexandroff compactification.

I had another idea more analytical that consists on constructing a function by putting the minima, for example in $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and to join them by using the exponential function on the $y$ axis.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know it's uneasy?

Comment: @A.G. nice point. Actually the title sounded good.

Comment: What went wrong with the Morse theory approach to the latter?

Comment: @PeteCaradonna I simply don't know it.

Comment: More low-tech: what if you imaged starting a construction by draping a rubber sheet over $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that it looks like the graph of $f(x,y) = e^y.$  Now, what if, you dropped two small, very dense balls onto the rubber sheet, suitably separated from each other, so that the 'pits' they form in the sheet get down to 0 (on the $z$-axis)? Edit: aha I see you had precisely the same idea.

Comment: With regard to the edit of the above, I think your latter approach is by far the best here.  Just gist is just that you only need to keep **all** partial derivatives from vanishing simultaneously, only one at a time is fine.

Comment: @PeteCaradonna what about the first approach: assuming that I don't know anything of Morse theory is it possible to do with elementary topology and some notion of basic algebraic topology (homotopy and fundamental group) to do the proof in a topological way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof: $f(x,y)=(x^2-1)^2+(x^2y-x-1)^2$ works.

Comment: I thought it was impossible to have a polynomial function of this type. Fortunately I was wrong. Thank you!